# Replacing Salesforce Marketing Cloud Connect with REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud

We are currently using Salesforce Sales and Marketing Cloud which are connected using Marketing Cloud Connect. However, we'd like to circumvent the Marketing Cloud Connect limitation of 15 minutes synchronisation time (meaning the earliest possible time to send out an email e.g. confirmation is 15 minutes after the data event).

Have any of you experience with using the Marketing Cloud's REST API as an interface to consume data from the Sales Cloud?

Thanks and best regards,
chrissik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will not recommend replacing the Marketing Cloud Connect, with REST API. If your use case is sending a confirmation email, when e.g. a new consumer is created as a contact, you can either use [triggered email sends](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_understand_triggered_sends.htm&type=5) to create and send automated messages to Salesforce contacts, leads, or person accounts when object records are created or updated - or use Journey Builder [Salesforce Data Entry events](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_salesforce_data_event.htm&type=5) to inject contacts into a journey. Both triggered sends and Salesforce data entry events are executed in real time, and do not require the synchronised data extensions being updated.

Removing the connector altogether leaves you without IMHO critical cross-cloud functionality, such as the ability to read and write records in Sales Cloud from AmpScript, Sales Cloud Journey Builder features (both entries and activities), and the capability of sending tracking information back to Service Cloud.